# How do I get CI curl command hooked up in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I want to connect with php to Mongo DB Api Endpoint.
I know that there are drivers for PHP.
But in my project it is not possible.

I have already created the endpoint in MongoDb.
I got the following output:

curl --location --request POST 'https://eu-central-1.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-zymtt/endpoint/data/v1/action/findOne' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: *' 
--header 'api-key: xxxxx
--data-raw '{
"collection": "geocoordinatescol",
"database": "geocoordinates",
"dataSource": "cluster0",
"projection": {"_id": "1}
}'

I am new to curl in php.
My question is how do I get this hooked up in PHP now.
I have read in the docs of PHP that you can set the header but how do I get the data-raw submitted?
Anahnd how can i save the returned JSON in an variable?

Would someone here have an example for me?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

i tried curl but without success.